# Tools required for windows 8 development / metro style apps?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7

I have been working on Windows Phone 7 app development, now I want to built metro style apps.

I have a set of doubts about the environment setup :-

1) Do we need Windows 8 OS for developing metro style apps?

2) Can we develop metro style apps in windows 7 OS?

3) What is Windows 8 Release Preview (Windows SDK) ?  What happens if I install that, can I do it in windows 7 OS?

4) What tools are required for metro style app development?

What do I need to download ?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, you need Windows 8 OS for the development of Windows 8 Metro apps
2. No, you cannot develop Metro apps in Windows 7
3. Windows 8 Release preview is the latest beta release of the Windows 8 OS. It's the pre-release version of Windows8 OS.

Windows 8 RP (Release Preview) is an OS, so you cannot install in Windows 7 unless you have a Virtual Box for doing so.

I suggest you to install Windows 8 RP in a separate partition, so that you will have an option of dual booting with Windows 7 and Windows 8. (But you will be able to use one OS at a time and you need to reboot to switch between the OS's)

You can download [Windows 8](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/download) from this link.

And then for Metro application development, you need [Visual Studio 2012 RC](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us/downloads)

Answer (score 2):

1) Yes, it's mandatory to use Windows 8 to develop Windows Store Apps.

2) No you can't develop Windows Store Apps using Windows 7. But you can always harness the power of Visual Studio 2012 in other possible ways.

3) Release Preview was eventually one of the test builds of Windows. Now the RTM is out so use RTM ONLY. YOU can always upgrade from Windows 7 to Windows 8.

4) You need Windows 8 RTM Installed + Visual Studio 2012 installed to work on Windows Store Apps.

Hope that might help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need windows 8 OS for metro style development using windows RT and Visual studio 2012.

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/155521/what-is-the-difference-between-windows-8-winrt-and-windows-rt

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8_editions

Try to install windows 8 os in a separate drive and install the VS 2012 because the preview version may slow down and crashes your system. Win Rt and a tool for WINDOWS phone 8 will going to release by microsoft this month end. So now you can practice metro style development on VS 2012 in Windows 8 OS.